# Git restore deleted branch merged without --no-ff

Tags: git

I merged two branches forgetting to use the --no-ff option, then I pushed to the origin.

I'd like to: restore the deleted branch, rollback before I merged the two branches without --no-ff, merge them again with --no-ff.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `committed to origin` do you mean push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start where you are, i.e. `group` branch being at the last commit of your feature branch, and `develop` is also at this commit since you merged `group` into it without fast-forward

Let's say `forkedSHA` is the SHA of the first commit where you started your feature, you have to reset master to the commit before:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard forkedSHA~
```

Now you're in the same situation as before you ran your merge, just do it again with `--no-ff`

```
git merge --no-ff group
```

and push it with force to `origin`

```
git push --force origin
```

If other people have pulled from `origin` in between they'll have to handle this change.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me. I was on `group` to add a new feature, then I merged it into `develop` forgetting `--no-ff`. Merging it without `--no-ff` now all `group`'s commit are shown in `develop` history. How do I restore `group` with its history before reset?

Comment: The `master` branch has not been modified, since I work on `develop`.